# ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'pymysql' in jupyter

Tags: python, python-3.x, pip, pymysql

I am getting below error after importing pymysql in jupyter notebook. Please help me to find error.

```
import pymysql
print("Welcome")

ModuleNotFoundError  
 <ipython-input-5-7978bc79cc40> in <module>()
  1 import pymysql
  2 print("Here")

 ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'pymysql'
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You have not installed the module `pymysql`
Try :

```
python -m pip install pymysql
```

Or

```
python3 -m pip install pymysql
```

for python3.

Comment: I already Installed through pip3 install pymysql . but still it's showing error.

Comment: You might have multiple Python versions (Python 2.7, 3.4, 3.7, 3.8, etc.) and `pymysql` was installed on a different one than used in Jupyter.

Comment: @Sourav_Bharadwaj Which version of python are you running the notebook?

Comment: Yes.It was mistake from my end. IDE python version and window python version was different. I just reinstalled the correct one and it's working fine.

Answer (score 2):

It appears that pymsql is not installed in your python environment you are working on.

Please type below command in a cell in jupyter notebook, then run the cell.

```
 !pip install pymysql
```

This should resolve your problem.

Comment: I have already installed pymysql.                                                             
C:\Users\Saurav Bharadwaj>pip3 list
Package                Version
---------------------- -------
cursor                 1.3.4
mysql-connector-python 8.0.21
mysqlclient            2.0.1
numpy                  1.19.0
pandas                 1.0.5
pip                    20.1.1
PyMySQL                0.10.0
pyodbc                 4.0.30
python-dateutil        2.8.1
pytz                   2020.1
SQLAlchemy             1.3.18
xlrd                   1.2.0

Comment: Maybe it is installed in different venv, try installing again via the same jupyter notebook.

Answer (score 0):

The reason why despite installation of the pymysql in your system, the issue **ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'pymysql'** occurs is because Anaconda does not recognize this.

Another solution to overcome this issue is to install pymysql in the Anaconda prompt.

[Issue:  **ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'pymysql'**](https://i.stack.imgur.com/O58hR.png)

[Solution: **Installing pymysql in Anaconda Shell**](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aoEID.png)

Thank you,
Narasimha Rao