# Python error "no module" when I try to run PIP

Tags: python, pip

I installed Python and checked the PATH box and made sure pip was check during install. I can see the `pip.exe` file in the python folder. I get this error when I try to install any package.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "<frozen runpy>", line 198, in _run_module_as_main
File "<frozen runpy>", line 88, in _run_code
File "C:\python-311\scripts\pip.exe\__main__.py", line 4, in <module>
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'pip'
```

Comment: use `python -m pip`

Comment: Does this answer your question? [ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'pymysql' in jupyter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62968439/modulenotfounderror-no-module-named-pymysql-in-jupyter)

Comment: @RoshinRaphel How does that help if pip doesn't work?

Comment: Can you try installing Python from the Windows Store instead?

Comment: Have you tried reinstalling python? That worked for me.

Comment: @OneCricketeer Pip maynot be installed as a separate module, but it comes with python by default. He can use `python -m pip install`.

Comment: Here is the error when I tried to run that command.
C:\python-311\python.exe: No module named pip

Comment: I have tried to reinstall python a couple times. My company has the Microsoft store turned off.

Comment: @RoshinRaphel Yes, it does come with Python, but if you read the post `pip.exe` is shown, but it is not working. Therefore, no command using it will work.

Answer (score 0):

```bash
python -m pip
```

or

```bash
pip3
```

should resolve your problem.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried following the [pip documentation](https://pip.pypa.io/en/stable/installation/)?

```
py -m ensurepip --upgrade
```

Or, to upgrade

```
py -m pip install --upgrade pip
```

Comment: I have followed all the documentation on both the python site and the PIP site. it still will not work.

Comment: I don't use Windows, so maybe Python 3.11 installation is broken? Try Anaconda or Python 3.10 as alternatives?

Answer (score 0):

Please is it solved? if not then please go to C:\python-311\scripts\pip.
If you see more than 2 or 3 pip, delete all and then leave only 1 pip which is 311 as in your C:.
Example pip, pip, pip311, all should be deleted leaving the pip with your python version on the C drive as shown above.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/35397333)